# How to insert image from URL in Jupyter Notebook (Markdown)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter-lab

I want to insert an image from a URL source in a Markdown code block in Jupyter Notebooks.

So far this is what I have:

```
![image info](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_map.png)
```

However, it doesn't include and image when I run the cell.

Answer (score 4):

Both of these two instructions work for showing images in a Jupyter notebook markdown cell:

```
![image info](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_map.png)
```

or with HTML

```
<img src="https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_mmap.png" alt="image info" />
```

The image is shown when the markdown cell is executed (*run*).

Answer (score 0):

I entered the code slightly differently from your code. I got the image to display when the markdown cell was run.

Below is the code used for displaying the .jpg in the Markdown cell. A photo of the output also follows below.

```
![image.png](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_map.png
```

Note: the code is not showing in the photo below because the Markdown cell was run - causing that .jpg to display and hide the code.  That's one big .jpg.  I would likely download a large .jpg file like that to the PC and then change the scale using a photo editor to make the .jpg smaller.  Then just use basically the same code but using some folder on the PC in the path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to insert an image in my Jupyter file on VS Code however it just kept giving no image. THIS WORKED FOR ME:

```
![PRO-STG1 - Pandas.png](<attachment:PRO-STG1 - Pandas.png>)
```

Initial square bracket contains the name of image and in the bracket put your file path.

So your code should look like this. Make sure you are in Markdown mode:

```
![Img_name](<attachment:image_path>)
```

Answer (score -2):

what you can do is that you can download the image using the requests library

```py
import requests
data = requests.get('https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_map.png').content
with open('image.png', 'wb') as file:
     file.write(data)
```